# C# WPF binding data in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, listbox

i have a problem in WPF application with binding data in ListBox.

Here is me xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="DatabaseBoozeWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatabaseBoozeWpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="625">
<Grid>
    <ListBox
             Margin="10,124,0,10"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Boozes}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             ItemTemplate="{Binding Boozes}"

             Width="233">

    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

But if I open the program, it will show this kind on text. It should output the list of products.
[image]

Comment: `ItemTemplate="{Binding Boozes}"` makes no sense. Declare an `ItemTemplate` in XAML. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: see here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Comment: Youc an just remove the ItemTemplate and override the ToString() Method of your boozes :)

Comment: @TobiasTheel Sure, but that's not the "WPF way".

Comment: @Clemens True, but it's working. Because of that reason i upvoted the answer of Sajeetharan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an ItemTemplate with a DataTemplate with elements that bind to the properties of the item class.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Boozes}" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```